# Snowflake Task does not start running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The task should run at 2:27am UTC, but it did not executed.

```
GRANT EXECUTE TASK ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE SYSADMIN;

CREATE or replace TASK TASK_DELETE3
WAREHOUSE = TEST
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 27 2 * * * UTC' as
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST2."PUBLIC"."DELETE" 
CLONE TEST1."PUBLIC"."DELETE";

ALTER TASK TASK_DELETE3 RESUME;
```

The task [state] = started.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

If the status shows that the task is started, that means it is enabled and will run in the scheduled times.

You can check the task history to see the previous runs and next run of the task using the following query:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.task_history(
task_name=>'TASK_DELETE3'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Gokhan.  I ran your command and saw the task history.  It seems like the task completed based on the "COMPLETED_TIME", but when I checked the TEST database, the table was not created.  I also checked history tab, and the "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE" was not executed at the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a different role when I was checking the table in the database. The Task successfully completed at scheduled time.